# Pandas + Scikit learn : issue with stratified k-fold

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When used with a Dataframe, `StratifiedKFold` from scikit-learn returns a list of indices from 0 to n instead of a list of values from the DF index. Is there a way to change that ?

Ex :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["test"] = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
df.index   = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(StratifiedKFold(df.index)):
    print i, (train, test)
```

Gives:

```
0 (array([], dtype=64), array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
1 (array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]), array([], dtype=64))
2 (array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]), array([], dtype=64))
```

I would expect the index from the df to be returned, and not the range of the length of the df...

Comment: Why is this a problem, note that the fact your index is assigned str values is irrelevant here. You're supposed to use the integer arrays to index into your df, you can just use `iloc` here

Comment: Well, I have an original df with an index ranging from 0 to 274, and then I subsample it to 0 to 30=> so I have 30 numbers between 0 and 274. Then I do s tratifiedkfold on this submatrix, and get figures from 0 to 30, while I have indexes ranging from 0 to 274.... This mean I got some 'nan' values from the kfolds...

Comment: Can you post code to reproduce this, thanks

Comment: unfortunately I can not copy paste to internet :(

Answer (score 3):

The numbers you got are just indices of `df.index` selected by `StratifiedKFold`.

To change it back to the index of your DataFrame, simply

```
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(StratifiedKFold(df.index)):
    print i, (df.index[train], df.index[test])
```

which gives

```
0 (Index([], dtype='object'), Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g'], dtype='object'))
1 (Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g'], dtype='object'), Index([], dtype='object'))
2 (Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g'], dtype='object'), Index([], dtype='object'))
```